# CSS Dropdown Not Functioning

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar, nav, genesis

I am using Genesis with a custom child theme and am having an issue with the navigation not working properly. For some reason the site is loading the sub navigation all the time. I want to only show the sub navigation when hovering. I have been messing around with the styles for a while now with no luck.

http://americasfinestlighting.com/

You can see the "Dropdown Nav Test" in the top left header.

Thanks, 
William

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Please don't post links to other sites. Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. If that link changes, this question won't make sense for future readers.